# String Value is not recognized by select statement passing identical string value

Tags: sql-server, string, replace, unicode, sqldatatypes

I'm struggling with pulling data using query below.

This problem occurs on all string values in that column. Even if I copy the actual value in SSMS from this table and the paste it into the select statement (`where string = 'MyStringVlaue'`). LTRIM/RTRIM functions also did not help.

Some info:

The database table source column data type is `VARCHAR(500)`.

My database compatibility level is 130. Using SSMS 2016. 
My Database Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
And my string Column Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

But it does not create any issues when querying the same string values which were original copied over from the problematic source table into other tables.

The problematic table was imported using SQL Server Import Wizard from an Excel file recognized by the Wizard as 2007-2010 type.

```
drop table #T
select 'MyStringVlaue' as String into #t
select * from #t where String ='MyStringVlaue' -- this does not return anything when executed on the Real table!
select * from #t
```

-- example

```
select ASCII('MEDICAL SERVICES DISTRICT') -- output is 65
```

**-- P.S.**

I created a copy of the problematic table by running `select * into from originalSourceTable`
Still has the same issue.

Comment: So give us an example of an actual string which doesn't work. And give us the collation of the column. And use the [ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function on every character in the string to see if any of them are *funny* ones.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I've just update the question with the requested info.

Comment: ASCII only works on one char at a time, so its painful, but you have to substring each char (currently you are only getting a result for the first char). That said your string looks fairly normal.

Comment: You're not storing a CR and/or LF char at the end of your string are you? That won't copy and paste so could cause what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TENTATIVE SOLUTION:**
It maybe a bug in SSMS itself. Once I opened a new query editor window and typed manually the same select statement the issue was gone. Though note, that I copied and pasted the code from old SSMS query editor window the issue still persists. It only helped when I type the code manually from the scratch.

Comment: Unlikely to be a bug, more likely a corrupt string.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are there are "invisible" characters in your database values, the usual culprit being trailing new line chars, but it could be anything eg tabs, vertical tabs, backspaces, etc.

Output the hex value of non-matching values like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(myStringColumn AS VARBINARY(4)),
    CAST('MEDICAL SERVICES DISTRICT' AS VARBINARY(4))
FROM mytable
WHERE myStringColumn like '%MEDICAL SERVICES DISTRICT%'
AND myStringColumn <> 'MEDICAL SERVICES DISTRICT'
```

You'll probably figure out the problem by inspection.

If you have unicode strings, use `VARBINARY(8)` instead of `VARBINARY(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

First a string value have no collation. Demo :

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(32) COLLATE French_CI_AI;
```

Will fail.

Second, when you create a temporary table (#) the collation is the tempdb collation. And this collation can be different of the context database collation.

Third, many solutions exists :

1) collating with default contextual DB :

```
select 'MyStringVlaue' COLLATE database_default as String into #t
```

2) collating with a specific one :

```
select 'MyStringVlaue' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as String into #t
```

3) auto collating with default contextual database :

if the database is partially contained…